# Matplotlib 3-d zoom does not zoom the axis

Tags: matplotlib

I tried following the demo on https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html. When I tried zooming, the plot points zoom however the axis remains at the place making it impossible to study outliers closely.

Image before zoom:
[image: Before zoom]

Image after zoom:
[image: Af]

How can I make the axis zoom(extend?) when zooming the plot.

Comment: There is no such option by default. Possibly one could implement a custom zoom tool that does something similar. Since navigating in 3D is not really easy, I think I would implement 3 sliders, one for each axis (or 6?) and use them to set the limits.

Comment: `mplot3d` is not a full 3D plotting solution, unfortunately. Consider using `mayavi` instead [see here, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739360/any-easy-way-to-plot-a-3d-scatter-in-python-that-i-can-rotate-around).